# How to get my class (which inherets dict) to allow double lookups? (typeerror)

Tags: python, dictionary, inheritance, defaultdict

I am trying (for fun) to implement a kind of defaultdict that always has the same structure. It is a nested defaultdict if n > 1 and a defaultdict (Lm) with defaultvalue 0 otherwise.

```
class Lm(dict):
def __init__(self, n=1):
    if n == 1:
        self.default = 0
    else:
        self.default = Lm(1)
    dict.__init__(self)

def __missing__(self, key):
    return dict.__setitem__(self, key, self.default)

def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
    except KeyError:
        return self.__missing__(key)
```

Since it is sometimes nested, I would like to be able to access entries like so (desired):

```
test = Lm(2)
test['i']['am']
print(test)
{'i': {'am': 0}}
```

However this does not work, I get the following error:

```
test = Lm(2)
test['i']['am']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I have found that if I lookup from `Lm` once before with the ['i'] it works as intended:

```
test = Lm(2)
test['i']
print(test)
{'i': {}}
test['i']['am']
print(test)
{'i': {'am': 0}}
```

Why does doing a lookup twice in the same line not work here?

**Edit:**
I figured it out, here is my updated code with the suggestions from below (including the bit about the defaultfactory).

```
class Lm(dict):
def __init__(self, n=1):
    if n == 1:
        self.default = lambda val: 0
    else:
        self.default = lambda val: Lm(1)

def __missing__(self, key):
    self.__setitem__(key, self.default(key))
    return self.default(key)

def __getitem__(self, key):
    try:
        val = super().__getitem__(key)
        self.__setitem__(key, val)
        return val
    except KeyError:
        self.__missing__(self, key, self.default(key))
```

Comment: `__setitem__` doesn't return anything, but you're trying to use its return (`None`) as the return of `__missing__`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I edited my answer for the correct wording! Does that mean I should remove the `return` when i call `__missing__` and in `__missing__` itself? I have tried, but the error remains. In fact the error is now `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`.

Comment: It seems like you just want `return self.default` in `__missing__`. Or `__setitem__`, then `return self.default`. Or have the `__setitem__` in `__getitem__` after the call to `__missing__`.

Comment: Once you fix the `__setitem__()` return value issue, you're going to run into a variation of the "mutable default argument" problem.  If you ever use two unknown keys, they're both going to be assigned the exact same instance of `Lm(1)` (that was assigned to `self.default`), so their values will be tied together.  This is precisely why the standard `defaultdict` doesn't take a default value as a parameter, it takes a default value constructor.